# Transactional rollback not working when called from Controller class but works when called from Test Class

Tags: java, database, spring, transactions

First of all, I've been looking for an answer to this but I still can't find an answer even after 5 hours of of searching.

Summary: My Transactional class does not rollback when it is called from my Controller class **but** when it is called in my JUnit test class, it executes the rollback.

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class NotifyServerController extends BaseController {

...

@RequestMapping(value = PathConstants.PATH_NOTIFY_SERVER, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public WiremoRoot notifyServer(// parameters //) throws SQLException {
    ... authentication and other if statements

    // State monitoring request (control box information)
    else if(content instanceof SpecificRequest){
        response.getContents().setContent(serviceObj.processRequest(request));
    }  else
        throw new InputErrorException();

    return response;
}

}
```

**ServiceObjectImplementation**

```
@Service(// Qualifier //)
@Transactional
public class ServiceClassImplementation implements ServiceClass {

    // -- Dao objects here

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public Response processRequest(// parameters //) throws SQLException {
        ...
        methodA();
    }

    public void methodA(){
        ...
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    ...

}
```

Please note that it successfully rolls back when it is called in my Test class. It just doesn't work when called from RestController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my tx-annotation statement was inside my db-context.xml that's why it was not working in the actual build but was working in my test class because in my test class, I load specifically the my configurations. So I put my tx-annotation statement in my dispatcherServlet(servlet-context.xml) and it worked.